# C# Docking to the edge of a desktop, popup issue

Tags: c#, wpf, docking, appbar

I'm making a WPF application which can be docked to one of the edges of the desktop. I do this by having an 'EdgeWindow' which is a transparent 5px wide window on the same edge of the screen, whenever the mouse goes over that then the window of the application will popup.

The problem is that while the 'EdgeWindow' is set to 'Topmost' other Windows applications also set their window to 'Topmost' which means that the EdgeWindow can end up underneath some windows. There doesn't seem to be a guaranteed way to keep the EdgeWindow on top as far as I can tell.

My application is already an 'ApplicationDesktopToolbar (similar to http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/csdoesshell3.aspx) so I was hoping there might be some way using that infrastructure to determine whether the window should popup and get rid of the 'EdgeWindow' entirely but I couldn't see anything there that would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I ended up using was to listen for any changes in the mouse position and pop up the window if it nears the edge. Of course, normal WPF mouse listening won't work when the cursor goes outside the application.

Original I planned to WH_MOUSE_LL but it seems like that functionality doesn't work well in Windows 7 since in Windows 7 they unregister any attached hooks every now and then for some reason.

Ultimately I ended up using 'RawInput' (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/rawinput.aspx) which works pretty well. The example only shows how to retrieve keyboard input events but it wasn't that difficult to change it to listen for mouse move events instead.

Comment: About to do this same thing. If you're willing to share your code, drop me a line. Would save me a few hours. thx

Comment: @HarryMexican Sorry, only saw this comment today. There is no private messages in StackOverflow so I can't 'drop you a line'. My email address is in my profile if you still want my code.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do a similar project a while using the ShAppBar class; if you are using the ShAppBar class, which you say you are, there shouldn't be a need to have an invisible topmost window. Also the link to the code you provided seems to contain the following:

```
GetAutoHideBar            = 0x00000007,    
// Registers or unregisters an autohide appbar for an edge of 

// the screen. 

SetAutoHideBar            = 0x00000008,    
// Notifies the system when an appbar's position has changed. 

WindowPosChanged          = 0x00000009,    
// Sets the state of the appbar's autohide and always-on-top 

// attributes.

SetState                  = 0x0000000a
```

Does this not work?

Comment: No essentially. Registering an AppBar on a particular side of the screen does not cause to window to actually popup, it simply informs Windows that you have an have an autohide application on that side of the screen.

Comment: What you could do instead then is set the working area of the screen to a few pixels less wide than what it is so that your application bar is always accessible to to the user. Changing the working area of the screen is fairly easy to do using screen.Bounds.Width.

Comment: My bad, I meant screen.WorkingArea.*